# Why is a Half-Mino Dungeoncrashing War Hulk Terrifying?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, optimization

Referencing my previous bad idea:
[How to Build a 3.5e Gnoll Pugilist](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/183944/how-to-build-a-3-5e-gnoll-pugilist/183948#183948)

In managing to explain why Gnolls are terrible PCs in 3.5 (yet providing a number of viable builds anyway), KRyan mentions that a Half-Minotaur Dungeoncrashing War Hulk is a terrifying thing to behold.

Before having my bad Gnoll idea, I'd toyed with a Dungeoncrashing War Hulk -- but what makes the Half-Mino more terrifying than a typical (also terrifying) War Hulk?

Comment: Should this have rather been a comment asking for clarification on the other answer?

Comment: Probably? I was expecting it to be a more complex answer...turns out it is self-evident because Half-Minos are STRONK if you grok the 'oh and you get all the benefits of gaining Large' fine print.

Comment: Would editing this Q to be more about how to build a Half-Mino War Hulk make it work better as a stand alone? Don't want to remove an answered question...

Comment: In general, you should avoid editing a question - especially an answered one - to change it so it asks something substantially different. Your proposed question might be good as a new/separate question (I'm not familiar enough with D&D 3.5e to make that assessment), but you shouldn't edit your current question to ask that instead.

Comment: Relevant Q&As on Meta: [When a Question Changes Completely, Should it be a New Question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6519/33569), [What kind of edits are acceptable to a question after an answer has been posted?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9094/33569)

Comment: Are you asking if/why a half-mino war-hulk would be stronger (perhaps unbalancing) than another option? Or are you asking why such a thing would be considered terrifying in-world...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s because dungeoncrasher war hulk is terrifying. Half-minotaur is just a pretty strong and efficient way to qualify for war hulk.

Comment: "Pretty strong"...I had missed some of the nuances of the template -- I see now that it is, indeed, "pretty strong" and as a template, can be stacked on other stuff. Mino-Ogre-Warforged-taurs sound interesting. :D

Comment: While Dungeoncrasher War Hulk being powerful can be taken as read, detailing how half-minotaur is an efficiency way to qualify would probably be a good addition. Possibility also covering that there isn't any (significant) synergies, but that negative might be tricky to show cleanly. Ideally, this answer would stand independently of it asking about one of your statements, but that's an oddity of the question vs how the site normally operates :)